# Backup and restore settings in Texstudio

Tags: texstudio

Does someone know, how to save all the settings of Texstudio and restore them in a simple way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The profile (`Menu > Options > Save/Load profile ...`) saves almost all settings except for window positions and macros. It is meant to be used in case you want to switch between configurations.

If you want to make a complete Backup, you can copy/replace the [settings file](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#where-are-the-settings-stored). Or the complete settings folder, which contains additional information like the recent files list, additional dictionaries, cwls an so on.

Answer (score 2):

Save with: Menu > Options > Save profile ...

Restore with: Menu > Options > Load profile ...