# Is there a way to import my configured settings from Texstudio on one PC to another?

Tags: texstudio

I am specifically interested in my syntax highlighting changes I made. Is there some kind of configuration file I can import to transfer my settings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backup and restore settings in Texstudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/322186/backup-and-restore-settings-in-texstudio)

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is well answered in this other question about restoring setting in TexStudio:
[Backup and restore settings in Texstudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/322186/backup-and-restore-settings-in-texstudio/323425)